# xaml binding - function difference

Tags: c#, function, xaml, binding

I am new to C# and xaml. One method below works and the other one does not. They look the same to me, both returning ObservableCollection.
If anyone tells me the difference or the terminology used for these functions, I can look for it as well.Thank you in advance.

```
//This one works when binded with xaml and displays the 

        public ObservableCollection<Emp> Items
        {
            get
            {

                collection.Add(new Emp { Name = "Emp1", Age = 21 });
                collection.Add(new Emp { Name = "Emp2", Age = 22 });
                return collection;

            }
        }

//This one does not work

    public ObservableCollection<Emp> collection = new ObservableCollection<Emp>();
            public ObservableCollection<Emp> Items()
            {


                collection.Add(new Emp { Name = "Emp1", Age = 21 });
                collection.Add(new Emp { Name = "Emp2", Age = 22 });
                return collection;
            }



   <!-- XAML CODE -->
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a property which is binded to a control on UI. When your application launches, that property's getter method will automatically get fired and hence will return the collection.

The second one is a method (not a property) and does not get executed automatically unless you call it from somewhere in your code. That is why 2nd one does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind only Properties to XAML and your first "method" happens to be a property. Remove the add calls from get section otherwise it will keep adding the same items to collection.

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/automatic-properties/ also check out automatic properties.

When binding properties that will change, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, otherwise the XAML does not know that it should update the binding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Cool trick is to use `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, you don't have to specify property name as a parameter every time.

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
```